# How to deal with matrix using the matrix itself in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
matrix_A <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1), nrow=3,ncol=4)
```

How could I get a new matrix by doing some operations on the matrix itself. The new matrix I want to get is like:
The first row is the **sum** of (the other rows * the first row), not %*%. The second row is the sum of (the other rows * the second row), etc. For example, the first row of new matrix would be processed like:
(the original second row) * (the original first row),that is [0 1 0 0] **+** (the original third row) * (the original first row),that is [0 0 1 0] , then we would get the final result, that is [0,1,1,0] .
the final new matrix of this example should be:

```
 0 1 1 0
 0 1 0 1
 0 0 1 1
```

Here is just a small matrix as an example, it actually may be large, but all elements are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
ta <- t(matrix_A)
t(sapply(seq(ncol(ta)), function(j) rowSums(ta[,j]*ta[,-j])))
```